# how to get the data stored into a array when select from dropdown using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data in to arrays

```
Var myObj = {
"myScale" : ['2','3','4','5'];
"myValues" : ['2.0','3.0','4.0','5.0'];
}

Var myObj2 = {
"myScale" : ['2','3','4','5'];
"myValues" : ['2.0','3.0','4.0','5.0'];
}
```

need to create dropdown menu dynamically from the above objects

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="myObj">
    <option >myScale</option>
    <option >myValues</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="myObj2">
    <option >myScale</option>
    <option >myValues</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

when i select option of myScale from myObj/myObj2 i need to get the values myObj/myObj2.myScale and print into document dynamically. I am fresher trying please help me.

Comment: Your array is not correctly organised, you should keep the `scales` as keys for the `values`

Comment: i made dummy arrays, its not key values, there lot will come. in future i will get more

"item1values" : ['2','3','4','5'];
"item2values" : ['2.0','3.0','4.0','5.0'];
"item3values" : ['2.0','3.0','4.0','5.0'];

i just want to print the values in page later with this values i need to plot graph. once i get the values of that items

Comment: your example is entirely wrong, and your way of defining arrays is wrong!, if you can enhance your example i can help you, even your HTML
Code is not like what you are describing

Comment: as explained just now, 

var myItem1Values=["1","2","3"];
var myItem2Values=["1","2","3"];
var myItem3Values=["1","2","3"];
the above arrays i need to print in options in dropdown then when i select myItem1Values i need to print the values of myItem1Values in document

Comment: Put some JS code you wrote! people can help you to correct that...
But asking whole logic is not a good SO way, It shows you searched noting on your problem

Comment: Please edit your question and make it more clear!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function addGroup(obj, label, combo){
    if(!combo) combo = $("<select/>");
    var group = $('<optgroup label="' + label + '"></optgroup>');
    combo.append(group);
    for(var i=0;i<obj.myScale.length;i++){
        group.append('<option value="'+obj.myValues[i]+'">'+obj.myScale[i]+'</option>');
    }
    return combo;
}
```

then call it like this:

```
var combo = addGroup(myObj, "myObj");
addGroup(myObj2, "myObj2", combo);
```

note that, this function in its first call above, creates a new combo, and for the others you can pass the created combo as its third parameter.

Or if you already have your select node in the page you can just do this:

```
addGroup(myObj, "myObj", $("#mycombo"));
addGroup(myObj2, "myObj2", $("#mycombo"));
```